# Command Line Tools for Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard, titanium-modules, command-line-tool

Where can I download Command Line Tools for Xcode 4.2 (Snow Leopard)?
It's not in https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
I need it to develop Titanium Android Module.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think if you download and install Xcode 4.2 then there is an option in Xcode->Preferences to automatically download and install the command line tools.

Comment: I have Xcode installed and in Preference there aren't any options

Answer (score 1):

I've checked my old laptop and I found the followings

The documentation says "The Xcode installer also installs system components and UNIX command line tools in a shared location on your Mac"

They are installed in the **/Developer/usr/bin** folder.

Comment: There aren't CLT component in list, only simulator (installed) and "ios 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support" (to install)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and couldn't find XCode 4.2 Command Lines.
too much to update to Lion or Lion Mountain just for some small compiling.

This may help you:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

download the install package for Snow leopard.

good luck.
Ken